# Figures and captions with a left shift in twoside documents using floatsetup

Tags: floats, scrbook, floatrow

I'm using `scrbook` class and configure floats by the `floatrow` package. In twoside documents it produces a left shift of 2pt for floats on odd pages.

How can align floats as on even pages?

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{floatrow,graphicx}

\floatsetup[figure]{  
margins=hangoutside,
capposition=beside,
capbesideposition={top,outside},
floatwidth=\textwidth,
capbesidewidth=\marginparwidth,
facing=yes,
objectset=centering
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]  
\includegraphics[draft]{file.pdf}
\caption{my shifted caption (left)}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[draft]{file.pdf}
\caption{my caption (right)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks (`\`…\``)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code ( just did this for you). You can do this by selecting these lines and clicking the "{}" button at the top or pressing ctrl-K (Windows/Linux) or cmd-K (Mac).

Answer (score 1):

The distance separating the figure and its caption has to be set equal to `\marginparsep`. The default value being `\columnsep`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{floatrow,graphicx}

\DeclareFloatSeparators{marginparsep}{\hskip\marginparsep} % <--------------

\floatsetup[figure]{  
margins=hangoutside,
capposition=beside,
capbesideposition={top,outside},
floatwidth=\textwidth,
capbesidewidth=\marginparwidth,
facing=yes,
objectset=centering,
capbesidesep = marginparsep  % <------------------
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]  
\includegraphics[draft]{file.pdf}
\caption{my shifted caption (left)}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[draft]{file.pdf}
\caption{my caption (right)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```